# Are gmail thread id's unique across users?

Tags: gmail-api

Title says it all, but I'd like to know if Gmail thread ids are unique across users. For various reasons I'd like to index a global datastructure based on these ID's.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's only unique for an individual user.  It's quite likely you'll get collisions across users as it's only a 64bit field and is largely time based.

If you need a Globally unique ID best to combine it with a user identifier.

Comment: Out of curiousity, where did you get your answer from?

Comment: message.id in the API is the same as Gmail IMAPs X-GM-MSGID, only 64 bits which is way too small to uniquely store every gmail message for every user ever.

see also:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions
and
http://mailman13.u.washington.edu/pipermail/imap-protocol/2014-July/002290.html

Answer (score 3):

Described on the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads) as unique ID, because: thread IDs are handles out of a special handle table and as such are always unique.

Comment: it claims its a unique id but doesn't specify whether its unique per user or globally unique.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the closest answer I could find, it might be worth posting in the [Gmail API group-forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmailagent), then the devs could answer you. :)

Comment: Stormie, that link you provide is for the "Gmail Agent API" which is not the same.  Stack overflow is the correct forum here.  See the gmail api docs https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/ which link directly here for Developer Resources

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with an gmail message ID of the form

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox/153899def4566ed5

Even when I was logged into a different gmail account, entering this URL brought me back to the google account that owns that address.

That suggests to me that this is indeed a globally unique identifier, though as Eric Defriez noted it seems too small.

Although the URL contains the string "inbox" when I archived the document the link still worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Message-Id` header if you are looking for unique cross-user identifier.

[How to find message id](https://www.accelo.com/resources/blog/how-to-find-an-email-s-message-id/) has been asnwered on this blog. Follow the link to find explanation.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)